# how to input from multiple .dat file?

Tags: c++, input, multiple-columns

I have a set of 101 files in `.dat` format (all contained in the same directory) with a recursive name: `smth_0.00.dat, smth_0.02.dat, smth_0.04.dat` etc. They consist of two sets of data: two columns of float numbers.
I need to extract then n-th line of data from each file and process it and repeat this for all n lines, in order to obtain n distinct values.

My problems are:

- create/use the right stringstream to recursively create the correct 100 filenames
- open it
- find a smart way to select (within each file) the n-th line, without having to make a for loop to read the entire columns

I tried to combine the information from other questions here on stackoverflow and this is what I came up with:

```
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        const int tot = 101 ; 

        std::string make_output_filename(size_t index) {
                std::istringstream ss;
                ss << "/filename_" << index << ".dat";
                return ss.str();
        }


        for (size_t n=0; n < tot; n++ )  {
                size_t i = n * 0.02 ;
                FILE *file = fopen(make_output_filename(i).c_str(), "r");
                cout << file << endl ;
                fclose(file);
        }
}
```

As you can see, for the moment I am just verifying if the code creates the right filenames by printing them on screen. Then opening would be just a matter of using

```
ifstream in; 
in.open("filename_0.00.dat");
```

However, if I try to compile it I get two error messages:

```
get_from_file4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
get_from_file4.cpp:12: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
get_from_file4.cpp:21: error: ‘make_output_filename’ was not declared in this scope
```

Could someone kindly help me to get out of this problem?

Comment: If you read the error messages, you'd notice that your make_output_filename function is not in the right spot, move it out of main function's scope.

Comment: The Boost Format library may be of use to you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

Answer (score 0):

1st problem is the placement of `make_output_filename`. This one is easy, as the compiler points it out. You can move it before `main`.

However, I see another problem that will almost surely rise:

`size_t i = n * 0.02;`

I am not sure how do you verify the filenames, 'casue the code obviously does not compile. But I am 99% sure this will cause problems. `size_t` is an integer type so multiplying it by something like `0.02` is always dangerous. It will get rounded down to `0` so for at least about 1st 50 iterations I would expect to see `filename_0`.

In your case I would make `i` a float and set appropriate flags of the `ss` stream inside `make_output_filename`.

If i got everything right the final would look something like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string make_output_filename(float number) {
  stringstream ss;
  ss.setf(ios_base::fixed);
  ss.precision(2);
  ss << "/filename_" << number << ".dat";
  return ss.str();
}

int main ()
{
   const int tot = 101 ; 
   for (size_t n=0; n < tot; n++ )  {
     float number = n * 0.02 ;
     cout << make_output_filename(number) << endl ;
   }
}
```

Comment: hi @luk32  I would only change one thing, the use of extra variables, your version is clearer, but I would tend to 
`int main ()
{
   const int tot = 101 ; 
   for (size_t n=0; n < (tot*2); n++ )  {
     cout << make_output_filename((float)n/100) << endl ;
   }
}`
for production code.

Comment: @GMasucci I tried to stick to the original. I would probably put float into `make_output_filename` and use it `make_out_filename(n)`. However I am curious why would you change the code like that? I somehow do not like splitting 0.02 into 2/100. Moreover, your code is not an equivalent. The incrementation step should be `n+=2`... See, that's why I would not mess up with the production code. You seem to complicated it to a point where bug was introduced =D. I'm very interested why.

Comment: erm @luk32 yep, ahem, well I have just done somthing I dont normally and it has proven why I dont normally: post code without testing.  The idea was to reduce the number of variables whilst still achieving the same output, however my assumptive code was wrong, apologies, it increments in steps of 0.01 when it should be steps of 0.02. Thank you for the extraordinarily polite correction; I shall now go hang my head in shame thoroughly.  I am going to leave these 2 posts of mine too, as a permanent reminder: think before I speak/type.

Comment: Umm, please, sir. If you checked my previous code in revision history you would let me join you for a cheer-beer in a pub. I was genuinely interested in your motivation. I think production code should be maintainable, being clear is a great deal of it. IMO reducing the number of variables brings no befits. And any tinkering on working code might end up badly. I also do not consider the code perfect, just because what happened. The real incrementation step is split across two places and makes it harder to understand literally three-line code on spot.

Comment: That's cool, at least you checked your code and didn't leave it up wrong.  Well enjoy that beer :) and I will do likewise:)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve a lot. my current (working) code is:

```
    string make_output_filename(float number) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss.setf(ios_base::fixed);
    ss.precision(2);
    ss << "/powerspectrum/cdm_matterpower_" << number << ".dat";
    return ss.str();
}

int main ()
{
    const int Nfile = 101 ;
    const int Nvalues = 926 ;
    double x[Nvalues], y[Nvalues], PowerL[Nvalues][Nfile] ;

    for (int l=0; l<Nvalues; l++) {
        for (int z=0; z < Nfile; z++ )  {
            float number = z * 0.02 ;
            cout << make_output_filename(number) << endl ;
            ifstream redout ;
            redout.open(make_output_filename(number).c_str());

            int nlines = 0 ;
            while (nlines < Nvalues) {
                redout >> x[Nvalues] >> y[Nvalues] ;
                if (nlines == l) {
                    PowerL[l][z] = y[Nvalues] ;
                    cout << "l = " << l << " , K = " << x[Nvalues] << " , P(k) = " << PowerL[l][z] << endl ;
                }
                if (!redout.good()) {
                    break;
                }
                nlines++;
            }
            redout.close() ;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, however, it reads the whole files at each z for loop (in order to extract the values that I then store in PowerL).
is there some more clever (i.e. computationally faster) way to do so?
thank you